# What is the declaration of data type "png_byte" in png.h library C?

Tags: c, libpng

Here, at the GitHub repo png.h library source code is given (https://github.com/LuaDist/libpng/blob/master/png.h).
But there also, directly they use the data type `png_byte`. I am looking for the declaration of this data type.

Comment: line 434: `# include "pnglibconf.h"` and line 457: `#  include "pngconf.h"` ... start by looking there -- rather than post on StackOverflow :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is in `pngconf.h`

```
typedef unsigned char png_byte;
```

Comment: .. at line 449.